# Cover $~E \to B~$ gives a homeomorphism $~E/Aut(E) \to B~$

Tags: general-topology

Let $p : E \rightarrow B$ be a cover s.t. Aut(E) acts transitively on $p^{-1}(b)$ for some fix $b \in B$. Then $E/Aut(E)$ is homeomorphic to $B$ where $Aut(E) \subset Cov(E,E)$. The problem is that I don't even understand how the map $~E/Aut(E) \to B~$ is defined, would someone please give me this definition?

Apparently it is "clear" but I fail to see this.

Comment: $\widetilde{x} \mapsto p(x)$? (Where $\widetilde{x}$ is the class of $x$ in $E/\!\mathrm{Aut}(E)$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's remove this question from the list of unanswered questions by up-voting this community wiki answer stating that Agusti Roig's comment above contains the right answer.

Answer (score -4):

Let's honor Rasmus' creative handling of the software restrictions by downvoting [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/cover-e-b-gives-a-homeomorphism-e-aute-b/5221#5221) self-referential community wiki answer.

Comment: Funny, for a moment I thought you got this idea from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39626/is-there-a-general-setting-for-self-reference but apparently that post turned up later.